# Installing tensorflow-model-server on centos/rhel

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

After hours of failed attempts I have come here.
I need to install tensorflow-model-server on a rhel box but the instructions are lacking and the manual compile failed.

These are the instructions for an apt-get install:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && \
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

I need the yum equivalent and don't know how.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: viewed 8 times.... by me